# Получение приложение с ionic io

Tags: ionic, ionicframework

Есть приложение на [ionic.io](https://apps.ionic.io/apps). Есть ли возможность скачать его с этого сервиса. Если есть, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце - 2 варианта, чтобы посмотреть приложение в ionic view http://view.ionic.io/

- сделать инвайт и зарегистрироваться с тем емейлом которому выслан инвайт и при входе вы увидите
- указать номер приложения и разово посмотреть его

http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/uploading_viewing.html

Comment: Я не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Я хотел бы исходный код получить.

Comment: Если вы сделали приложение в creator и хотите начать его редактировать  ionic start [appName] creator:xxxwsssdsdsds

Comment: https://youtu.be/CBsBKRriZFI?list=PLOMESIqyrpf-rpNjFGzuCoTwNdv_-PUD1